# Node.js - npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\username

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I installed Node.js in my machine (`Windows 10`) and when I execute the `npm install -g` on the `Node.js command prompt` window I get some errors like below:
[image]
What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you're running cmd or powershell with administrative rights. Looks like your machine is locked down.

Answer (score 1):

Two details:

- The penultimate line in that image still shows the username :P
- The error says npm has no read permissions in that directory: "Ilegal operation on a directory, **read**"

Try with an administrator command line window

Answer (score 1):

Same Problem I faced. Try this command, Its working fine.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

[image]